# Reference bootstrap.min.js in React application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router

I need to include both jQuery and bootstrap.min.js in my react application. Right now I have both bootstrap and jQuery installed via npm. Im importing bootstrap.less in my less file, I just need bootstraps JS and jQuery.

The issue is; I'm using jQuery in my application for AJAX, and I don't know where to include the bootstrap.min.js.

I will try to provide as much info as possible to help. My main entry file is an App.jsx that utilizes all routes from react-router. My less file import looks like this.

```
@import "./../../node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```

my layout.pug looks like this

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no")
        meta(http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge")
        title #{ siteName } Administration
        link(rel="icon shortcut", href="/favicon.ico", type="image/x-icon")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href=maincssfile)
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css")
    body
        block content
            h1 Default Content
        script(src=mainjsfile)
```

Im using bootstrap3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with .pug files, but you should be able to include a link to a cdn for each of the two js files you need under where you link the bootstrap css cdn, that's how we have it laid out in my app's index html file.

Comment: Yeah that is my last resort. I would like to just use the modules rather than CDN's, but it definitely looks like I will be taking that approach.